# Counting number of UIViews that have been randomly tapped from a number of UIViews, ie: random 5 UIViews tapped from 9 UIViews, then do action

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I am new to Objective c and have looked around for days but could not find the answer. I have 9 imageViews in a container view and every one of them can only be tapped once, I want to do something after random 5 UIImageViews have been tapped. Here is the code I used for each one of them to experience one tap. If have to change the code I will, so please provide any help.

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveToNextMovingRectangle:)];

    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    [self.imageView1 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [self.imageView2 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [self.imageView3 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [self.imageView4 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [self.imageView5 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [self.imageView6 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [self.imageView7 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [self.imageView8 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [self.imageView9 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

//    if (5 random imageShapes have been tapped){
//        
//        do something
//    }
```

Comment: FYI, A UITapGestureRecognizer instance can only be attached to one view. You need to make a new one for each view.

Comment: tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 9; should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new counter variable and increase it's value every time while user tap on the images and when it reaches to 5 you can do whatever you want.Like this Way :

First declare globel counter variable in `ViewController` class like :

```
var counter : Int = Int()


UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveToNextMovingRectangle:)];

tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[self.imageView1 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[self.imageView2 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[self.imageView3 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[self.imageView4 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[self.imageView5 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[self.imageView6 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[self.imageView7 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[self.imageView8 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[self.imageView9 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
self.moveToNextMovingRectangle()

}


   func moveToNextMovingRectangle(){ 

 // Increment in counter value 
    counter += 1;
    if (counter>=5)
    {
        //do what ever you want
    }
    else {
        //get a random number using  arc4random() method and show your next imageview
    }
}
```

I think this will work try it.

Comment: how can I make the counter that counts the number of taps? The counters I make cannot count the taps, or the tapped images.

Answer (score 0):

suppose if we have saved our imagesviews in nsarray and a counter to keep track of taps

```
NSArray *imgViews = @[self.imageView1,self.imageView2.....,self.imageView9];  
int counter;
```

after that in your selector do this

```
-(void) moveToNextMovingRectangle{  
counter +- 1;
    if (counter>=5)
    {
        //do what ever you want
    }
    else {
        //get a random number using  arc4random() method and show your next imageview
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to link the number of taps to the counter or the tapped imageViews to the counter. Please make it clearer for someone new like me.

Comment: we have used a global variable named counter and incremented it on each tap of imageview, see moveToNextMovingRectangle selector